# What's the idea behind ObjectProperty in this example from the Kivy docs?

Tags: python, kivy

I really try to get the concept of Kivy. I'm aware it's powerful and useful, but for me at some points also hard to understand, at least by the given examples in [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html). In the section "Designing with the Kivy Language" I found following example:

Python-file

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty

class Controller(FloatLayout):
    ''' Create a controller that receives a custom widget from the kv lang file.
    Add an action to be called from the kv lang file.    '''
    # label_wid = ObjectProperty()
    info = StringProperty()

    def do_action(self):
        self.label_wid.text = 'My label after button press'
        self.info = 'New info text'

class ControllerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Controller(info='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ControllerApp().run()
```

controller.kv

```
<Controller>:
    label_wid: my_custom_label

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20

        Button:
            text: 'My controller info is: ' + root.info
            on_press: root.do_action()

        Label:
            id: my_custom_label
            text: 'My label before button press'
```

There is some little deviation from the original:  I made the line **# label_wid = ObjectProperty()** a comment, trying out to get the idea behind it, expecting the code not to run. But it is running! So would someone with a better understanding of Kivy be so kind to explain, why this line of code is useful (maybe at least for educational reasons), if not yet required (by any circumstance, of which I'm not aware of)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a kv line for a property that doesn't exist, it is automatically created, so the kv is actually the same in this case as putting `label_wid = ObjectProperty()` in the python. However, adding the property in Python is more explicit (especially if you will access it from python) and lets you be certain that a property of the right type will be created.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this! For a beginner like me, these little details can be very confusing. I now remember I read s.th. like that in the docs before, but forgot it afterwards (or couldn't applicate it in this context adequately), maybe because of all the other stuff I 've to learn about it.